Incrementing adjacent mines in minesweeper using Python
I'm currently struggling to get the cells adjacent to mines(#) to increment based on how many mines are next to them.
My current code is returning 0 instead of incrementing - please can anyone help?
The main issue I'm having is my border_check function is calculating but not storing the counts to my new_grid variable
positions = [[-1, -1], [-1, 0], [-1, 1], [0, -1], [0, 1], [1, -1], [1, 0], [1, 1]]

mine = "#"
dash = 0
grid = [
    ["-", "-", "-", "#", "#"],
    ["-", "#", "-", "-", "-"],
    ["-", "-", "#", "-", "-"],
    ["-", "#", "#", "-", "-"],
    ["-", "-", "-", "-", "-"],
]

def minesweeper(grid):
    new_grid = [[[dash, mine][col_i == mine] for col_i in row] for row in grid]
    def border_check(new_grid):
        for row_i, row in enumerate(grid):
            for col_i, value in enumerate(row):
                for dr, dc in positions:
                    def increment(new_grid):
                        if row_i + dr in range(len(value)) and col_i + dc in range(
                        len(row)
                    ):
                            if (
                            new_grid[row_i + dr][col_i + dc] == mine
                            and grid[row_i][col_i] != mine
                        ):
                                new_grid[row_i][col_i] +=1
                        return increment(new_grid)
        return border_check(new_grid)
    def minesweeper_output(new_grid):
        for row in new_grid:
            for col_i in row:
                print(col_i, end=" ")
            print()
    return minesweeper_output(new_grid)
minesweeper(grid)

This is the output I need:
1 1 2 # # 
1 # 3 3 2 
2 4 # 2 0
1 # # 2 0
1 2 2 1 0


This code makes no sense at all.  In at least two cases, the only call to a function is inside that function, so it can never be called at all.

I would definitely suggest refactoring your code to begin with. Separate the functions, make sub-functions to avoid the nested loops, etc... That will only help you when trying to debug.

I made a separate function to count mines around a row,coll on the board. You can use it to just check a row,col for mines around it. Here is:
mine = "#"

grid = [
    ["-", "-", "-", "#", "#"],
    ["-", "#", "-", "-", "-"],
    ["-", "-", "#", "-", "-"],
    ["-", "#", "#", "-", "-"],
    ["-", "-", "-", "-", "-"],
]

def minesweeper_output(g):
   for row in g:
      for col_i in row:
         print(col_i, end=" ")
      print()
   return

# Function returns the count of mines around a location on the board
#    # - -
#    - x -
#    # - #   for a count of 3 
#           the cell itself at offset (r,c) isn't counted 
def border_checker(g,r,c):
   if g[r][c] == mine: return mine
   n = 0
   rangeX = range(0, len(g[0]))  # X bounds 
   rangeY = range(0, len(g))  # Y bounds
   for X in range(c-1,c+2): # left, here, right by col
      for Y in range(r-1,r+2): # up, here, down by row
         if (X in rangeX) and (Y in rangeY): # on the board?
           if (Y,X) != (r,c) and g[Y][X] == mine: # neighbor is a mine? 
              n += 1
   return n 
    
def minesweeper(grid):
   new_grid = grid.copy()
   for i in range(len(new_grid)): 
      for j in range(len(new_grid[0])): 
        new_grid[i][j] = border_checker(new_grid,i,j) 
   minesweeper_output(new_grid) 
   return 
minesweeper(grid)

Output:
$ python mines.py 
1 1 2 # # 
1 # 3 3 2 
2 4 # 2 0 
1 # # 2 0 
1 2 2 1 0 


Your embedded functions complicate things and in fact return increment(new_grid) stops your loops after the first iteration.  I removed the embedded functions and fixed the bug marked below:
positions = (-1, -1), (-1, 0), (-1, 1), (0, -1), (0, 1), (1, -1), (1, 0), (1, 1)

mine = "#"
dash = 0
grid = [list('---##'),
        list('-#---'),
        list('--#--'),
        list('-##--'),
        list('-----')]

def minesweeper(grid):
    new_grid = [[[dash, mine][c == mine] for c in row] for row in grid]
    for r, row in enumerate(grid):
        for c, value in enumerate(row):
            for dr, dc in positions:
                # grid not value here --\
                if r + dr in range(len(grid)) and c + dc in range(len(row)):
                    if new_grid[r + dr][c + dc] == mine and grid[r][c] != mine:
                        new_grid[r][c] +=1
    return new_grid

def minesweeper_output(new_grid):
    for row in new_grid:
        for c in row:
            print(c, end=" ")
        print()

new_grid = minesweeper(grid)
minesweeper_output(new_grid)

Output:
1 1 2 # # 
1 # 3 3 2 
2 4 # 2 0 
1 # # 2 0 
1 2 2 1 0 


Your minesweeper function is not actually evaluating any function besides minesweeper_output(new_grid). There's a couple things we need to clean up here. First, to execute a function, you should not be calling return. Second, the calls are placed inside of the defined functions instead of after, and they are therefore not being executed at all. The simplest fix here would be to left-shift return increment(new_grid) and return increment(new_grid), and remove the return calls. This will at least allow your code to fully execute.
I have also removed a few of your function definitions from inside minesweeper() to increase readability. I left increment() on the idea that you probably didn't want to pass all of those values to it, so its easier if the function is defined within the scope of border_check()
positions = [[-1, -1], [-1, 0], [-1, 1], [0, -1], [0, 1], [1, -1], [1, 0], [1, 1]]

mine = "#"
dash = 0
grid = [
    ["-", "-", "-", "#", "#"],
    ["-", "#", "-", "-", "-"],
    ["-", "-", "#", "-", "-"],
    ["-", "#", "#", "-", "-"],
    ["-", "-", "-", "-", "-"],
]

def minesweeper_output(new_grid):
    for row in new_grid:
        for col_i in row:
            print(col_i, end=" ")
        print()

def border_check(new_grid):
    def increment(new_grid):
        if row_i + dr in range(len(value)) and col_i + dc in range(len(row)):
            if new_grid[row_i + dr][col_i + dc] == mine and grid[row_i][col_i] != mine:
                new_grid[row_i][col_i] +=1

    for row_i, row in enumerate(grid):
        for col_i, value in enumerate(row):
            for dr, dc in positions:
                increment(new_grid)

def minesweeper(grid):
    new_grid = [[[dash, mine][col_i == mine] for col_i in row] for row in grid]
    border_check(new_grid)
    minesweeper_output(new_grid)


minesweeper(grid)

This problem isn't done though, as increment is not correctly counting every mine, but I will leave that to you to figure out.

You should skip the counting loop for mine positions rather than test for mines within the counting logic.
Using the continue statement can make the code a bit easier to read:
grid = [
    ["-", "-", "-", "#", "#"],
    ["-", "#", "-", "-", "-"],
    ["-", "-", "#", "-", "-"],
    ["-", "#", "#", "-", "-"],
    ["-", "-", "-", "-", "-"],
]
mine     = "#"
rowRange = range(len(grid))
colRange = range(len(grid[0]))
offsets  = [(r,c) for r in range(-1,2) for c in range(-1,2) if r or c]
for row in rowRange:
    for col in colRange:
        if grid[row][col] == mine: continue                 # skip mine pos.
        mineCount = 0                                       # count mines
        for rowOffset,colOffset in offsets:                 # look around
            mineRow, mineCol = row+rowOffset, col+colOffset
            if mineRow not in rowRange: continue            # inside grid
            if mineCol not in colRange: continue
            mineCount += ( grid[mineRow][mineCol] == mine ) # +1 for mine
        grid[row][col] = str(mineCount)                     # assign count

output:
print(*map(" ".join,grid),sep="\n")

1 1 2 # #
1 # 3 3 2
2 4 # 2 0
1 # # 2 0
1 2 2 1 0

